# (Python) Script to determine if (x, y) coordinates are colinear - getting some errors

Tags: python, list, function, graph, points

like the title says, I'm trying to write a program that takes a list of (x, y) coordinates, and determines if any 3 points are collinear (lie on a line with the same slope)

I'm getting some error messages.  As it stands, I get an "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" message.  If I take out the part where collinearityTest calls on the areCollinear function, I get an "index out of range" error.  I'm new to python, and just trying to learn.

```
def areCollinear(p1, p2, p3):
    slope1 = (p2[1] - p1[1]) / (p2[0] - p1[0])
    slope2 = (p3[1] - p2[1]) / (p3[0] - p2[0])
    if slope1 == slope2:
        print "Points are colinear"
    else:
        print "Points are NOT colinear, what's the matter with you?"

def collinearityTest(pointList):
    position = 0
    while position >=0 and position < len(pointList):

        for p1 in pointList[position]:
            position = position + 1
            for p2 in pointList[position]:
                position = position + 1
                for p3 in pointList[position]:
                    position = position + 1
                    areCollinear(p1, p2, p3)

pointList = [(10, 20), (55, 18), (10, -45.5), (90, 34), (-34, -67), (10, 99)]

collinearityTest(pointList)
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 19, in collinearityTest
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 2, in areCollinear
    if __name__ == '__main__':
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the code that's giving you the error. Edit your question to include that.

Comment: Please post your code. Without it your question is basically impossible to answer.

Comment: telling me that it's horrible code doesn't really move this along.  a thousand thanks for your input however

Comment: Please post the full error. We can't guess (well, we probably could with some effort) the line that generates it.

Comment: In your code and several of the answers the floating point slopes of the two lines formed by each group of three consecutive points is compared for equality. In general that's unlikely to work because of the way floating point computations are done. You need to use a different method (like the one suggested by @Sven), or compare the absolute value of the difference between the two slope to some small floating point value that's almost zero, such as `1e-12`.

Answer (score 13):

Here's an easier and numerically more robust and stable function to test the collinearity of three points:

```
def collinear(p0, p1, p2):
    x1, y1 = p1[0] - p0[0], p1[1] - p0[1]
    x2, y2 = p2[0] - p0[0], p2[1] - p0[1]
    return abs(x1 * y2 - x2 * y1) < 1e-12
```

(Note that it would be best not to hard-code the epsilon, and to make it relative to the length of the vectors.)

Comment: Note to OP: This is the magnitude of the cross product between two 2D vectors.  If this value is zero, then the points are collinear.

Comment: @Darthfett: There are different ways to look at this.  It could also be interpreted as the derterminant of the two vectors, since it is rather unusual to define the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) in two space dimensions.  Yet another way to interpret this is to simply multiply the identity used in the original post by the occurring denominators.

Comment: It's also proportional to the area of the triangle between the two vectors (a triangle with zero area is two parallel lines which originate from the same point).  I just wanted to give the OP a bit of explanation as to why/how it works.  Since the context is 'points', using Cross Product is something that extends to 3D points.

Comment: It should be `abs(x1 * y2 - x2 * y1) < eps`

Comment: But what if they are 3d points? Your code won't work.

Comment: @ShaunHan Sure, since the OP asked a different question. You can use the _cross product_ of (p1 - p0) and (p2 - p0) to estimate the area of the triangle formed by the three points. If that area is sufficiently small compared to the length of the longest edge of the triangle, you can consider the points collinear.

Answer (score 4):

### The Error

The main error is that you are trying to access part of the `int` object, but it is not possible. You can reproduce similar error like this:

```
>>> p1 = 1
>>> p1[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    p1[1]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

### Other problems

You have several problems with your code, especially two come in mind:

1. Divisions (you are not using Python 3.x, so `/` works in a way different than you want, eg. the following is true: `3/2==1` - you should use divisions involving `float`s or at least use `from __future__ import division`),
2. Three levels of loops - this is bad idea because of complexity, just use `itertools.combinations` instead.

### Framework for improvements

You should just do something like:

```
import itertools

for x, y, z in itertools.combinations(pointList, 3):
    # Check if x, y and z lie on the same line,
    # where x, y and z are tuples with two elements each.
    # And remember to use floats in divisions
    # (eg. `slope1 = float(p2[1] - p1[1]) / (p2[0] - p1[0])`)
    pass
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [rank of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) (i.e. a 2D array) to determine whether its columns (interpreted as lists of coordinates) are collinear: Its rank is one, if and only if all the points are collinear with the origin.

This is true in all dimensions, and with any number of columns (i.e. any number of points).

Note that if we shift collinear points by a constant offset then they remain collinear, a property which we will need to use the above property (since the points in the matrix need to be collinear with the origin to use the matrix rank property).

An elegant approach using [`numpy.linalg.matrix_rank`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_rank.html) is therefore:

```
from numpy.linalg import matrix_rank

def are_collinear(coords, tol=None):
    coords = np.array(coords, dtype=float)
    coords -= coords[0] # offset for collinear points to intersect the origin
    return matrix_rank(coords, tol=tol)==1
```

with usage in the case of three points: `are_collinear([p0, p1, p2])`. But you could plug in an iterable with any number of points, not just three, e.g. your `pointList` list.

Here are a couple of further examples:

```
# Non-collinear example
are_collinear(np.random.rand(10, 2)) # False

# Collinear examples
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = 2 * x + 1
z = 3 * x + 2
are_collinear(np.c_[x, y]) # True
are_collinear(np.c_[x, y, z]) # True
```

Comment: This does not seem to work: `x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100); y = 2 * x + 3; are_collinear(np.c_[x, y])` returns False.

Comment: This approach does work if the line passes through the origin, hence `matrix_rank(points - points.mean(axis=0)[np.newaxis, :], tol=tol) == 1` works as intended.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen Good point. I think a simpler (and more efficient) remedy, rather than subtracting the mean, is just subtracting the first point. It doesn't matter what we subtract, as long as we subtract something what would cause a co-linear set of points to intersect the origin.

Comment: Great point. Feel free to replace my edits with your more efficient solution.

Comment: Got this code to work, but needed to explicitly set the type of `points` to a float for my needs.  like this: `np.array(points, dtype='float64')`

Answer (score 3):

Your code could be much cleaner:

```
import itertools

def arecolinear(points):
    xdiff1 = float(points[1][0] - points[0][0])
    ydiff1 = float(points[1][1] - points[0][1])
    xdiff2 = float(points[2][0] - points[1][0])
    ydiff2 = float(points[2][1] - points[1][1])

    # infinite slope?
    if xdiff1 == 0 or xdiff2 == 0:
        return xdiff1 == xdiff2
    elif ydiff1/xdiff1 == ydiff2/xdiff2:
        return True
    else:
        return False

pointlist = [(10, 20), (55, 18), (10, -45.5), (90, 34), (-34, -67), (10, 99)]

for points in itertools.combinations(pointlist, 3):
    if arecolinear(points):
        print("Points are colinear")
    else:
        print("Points are NOT colinear")
```

Comment: The key here being that they python library `itertools` already has a function to create combinations of elements in a list: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: @nightcracker: Are you aware that `1.8/1` is not equal to `18/10` in Python 2.x, which is used clearly in this example?

Comment: @Tadeck: The OP clearly used Python 2.x, but the code in this answer is not specific to 2.x or 3.x.

Comment: @Tadeck: Yes I'm aware, I'll add a `float` in there to prevent that bug. I was just lazy :P

Comment: @SvenMarnach: When I was looking at the answer, the code was clearly specific to 2.x (vide: `print` statements instead of functions). But indeed it may not be 2.x-specific right now.

Comment: @Tadeck: I do my best to write version-agnostic code, but I'm used to __always__ use `from __future__ import print_function, division`, so please excuse my error.

Comment: 1. Some indices seem to be wrong in the definition of `xdiff2` and `ydiff2`.  2. Assuming your divisions are meant to be floating point divisions, you shouldn't compare the results with `==`, but rather allow for a small relative error.

Comment: @nightcracker: Ok, I will upvote it now :) Just take Sven's notices into account and correct your code - he is right at least about comparison (I did not check the first point).

Comment: @Tadeck: I fixed the first point and I honestly can not be arsed about putting in a epsilon for the float comparison. That's left as an exercise for the OP :P

Answer (score 1):

So you want to have 3 for loops and each of them are iterating through the same list of points. Then why do you have the while loop? Just remove it. It's needless in this case.

Furthermore; `pointList[position]` is a 2d tuple, e.g (10,20). And by writing `for p1 in pointList[position]`, you are trying to iterate over that tuple. What you want is to iterate over the list. So try `for p1 in pointList` instead. I.e., remove the angle brackets to iterate over the list, not the tuple. Therefore; you don't need to keep track of position as well.

So it becomes

```
for p1 in pointList:
  for p2 in pointList:
    for p3 in pointList:
        #do something with p1 p2 p3
```

**Tip:** You might also consider having `areCollinear` function return a boolean value instead of printing something. Doesn't really change the functionality but it's a better practice, as it makes your function reusable somewhere else later on.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `itertools.combinations()`, but since you're trying to learn Python, here's your basic problem: you're going a level deeper into `pointList` than you need to.

Modified function:

```
def collinearityTest(pointList):
    for p1 in pointList:
        for p2 in pointList:
            if p2 is p1:
                continue
            for p3 in pointList:
                if p3 is p2 or p3 is p1:
                    continue
                areCollinear(p1, p2, p3)
```

`for p1 in pointList` will give you each item in `pointList`. That's exactly what you want. You could also do this with indexes (`pointList[index]`) if you like.

Again, go for `itertools.combinations()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am confused by the "if p2 is p1" and the "if p3 is p2 or p3 is p1"  I have never seen anything like this before.  What does this do?

Comment: Obviously you don't want to compare whether two identical points are collinear.  Since you're iterating over the same list 3 times, this avoids any scenario with where either `p1` and `p2`, `p2` and `p3`, or `p1` and `p3` are all the same element of `pointList`.  itertools' combination has an identical result (all possible different combinations of `pointList`).

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with the other answers, such as checking for divide by zero.  Here's my solution that uses the "All" Python feature and can check a point list of any length:

```
def collinear(Points):
    '''Accepts [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...] and returns true if the 
    points are on the same line.'''
    ERR=1.0e-12
    if len(Points)<3:
        return True
    x1, y1 = Points[0]
    x2, y2 = Points[1]
    if x2==x1:
        raise Exception("points are not a function")
    m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
    return all([abs(m*(xi-x1)-yi+y1)<ERR for xi,yi in Points[2:]])
```