# How can I check if all given points (in space) lie on the same line?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, math, geometry

I need to implement a function that takes coordinates of any number of points as input data and return **True** or **False** depending on whether these points lie on the same line or not.

I use Python to solve this problem and now I have the following implementation:

```
def are_colinear(points, tolerance): # variable "points" is a list of lists with points coordinates
    for i in range(2, len(points)):
        if (points[i][0] - points[i-2][0])/(points[i-1][0] - points[i-2][0]) - (points[i][1] - points[i-2][1])/(points[i-1][1] - points[i-2][1]) < tolerance and \
           (points[i][1] - points[i-2][1])/(points[i-1][1] - points[i-2][1]) - (points[i][2] - points[i-2][2])/(points[i-1][2] - points[i-2][2]) < tolerance:
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

This method is based on the equation of a line passing through two points:

[image]

The weakness of this approach is that it raises an error if you want to check points belonging to the same plane (one of three coordinates always equals to zero in this case and one of denominators is zero because of this). I need a better implementation. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If a/b == c/d, then ad == bc. Comparing floating point numbers for equality is not a good idea anyway.

Comment: Take one point as the origin, then determine the relative positions (rx, ry) of the other points. Calculate "slopes" rx / ry, check that all these slopes are equal (you can use Python fractions to do this exactly - what will happen under the hood when you compare the fractions will roughly be what n.m. has outlined); if any `ry` is zero, check that all points have the same y coordinate.

Comment: You could crank your points through a [linear regression](https://realpython.com/linear-regression-in-python/) model, and see if the residual variance is less than your tolerance. That would generalize to any number of dimensions.

Comment: `are_colinear = np.linalg.matrix_rank(points - points[0]) == 1`, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69007875/240443). Might want to give `tolerance` as second argument to `matrix_rank` if you have floating point precision issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any one of your coordinates, take it to be your new origin, translating all coordinates accordingly. Now, treat each coordinate as a position vector. Normalize each vector.  Now, if any two vectors are parallel, their dot product is 1. In fact, they are the same vector. If two vectors are antiparallel, their dot product is -1 and one vector is the negation of the other.

When you expand it all out, you'll find that you don't need to do any divisions, can avoid any square roots, **and don't have special edge cases to handle**.

```
1 ?= abs(dot(norm(u), norm(v)) 
   = abs(dot(u, v) / (mag(u) * mag(v)))
   = dot(u, v)^2 / (mag(u) * mag(v))^2

1 = (ux*vx + uy*vy + uz*vz)^2 / (sqrt(ux^2 + uv^2 + uz^2) * sqrt(vx^2 + vy^2 + vz^2))^2
1 = (ux*vx + uy*vy + uz*vz)^2 / ((ux^2 + uv^2 + uz^2) * (vx^2 + vy^2 + vz^2))

(ux^2 + uv^2 + uz^2) * (vx^2 + vy^2 + vz^2) = (ux*vx + uy*vy + uz*vz)^2
```

This is pretty easy to code up:

```py
def are_parallel(points):
    points = set(points)  # dedupe
    if len(points) < 3:
        return True

    xo, yo, zo = points.pop()  # extract origin

    translated_points = [(x-xo, y-yo, z-zo) for x, y, z in points]
    ux, uy, uz = translated_points[0]  # first/reference vector
    u_mag_sqr = ux**2 + uy**2 + uz**2

    for vx, vy, vz in translated_points[1:]:  # rest of vectors
        v_mag_sqr = vx**2 + vy**2 + vz**2
        uv_dot_sqr = (ux*vx + uy*vy + uz*vz)**2
        if u_mag_sqr * v_mag_sqr != uv_dot_sqr:
            return False
    return True
```

Again, its worth emphasizing that this avoids division, square roots, or anything that would introduce floating-point comparison to what could otherwise be integer coordinates, its faster because its just multiplications and additions, and it doesn't have weird edge cases around specific classes of coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

You can improve your implementation to handle cases where one of the three coordinates is always zero by making the code more robust. Here's an updated implementation of your function:

```py
def are_colinear(points, tolerance):
    if len(points) < 3:
        return True

    for i in range(2, len(points)):
        x1, y1, z1 = points[i - 2]
        x2, y2, z2 = points[i - 1]
        x3, y3, z3 = points[i]

        # Check for division by zero and avoid it by using a tolerance
        if abs((x1 - x2) * (y2 - y3) - (x2 - x3) * (y1 - y2)) > tolerance or \
           abs((x1 - x2) * (z2 - z3) - (x2 - x3) * (z1 - z2)) > tolerance or \
           abs((y1 - y2) * (z2 - z3) - (y2 - y3) * (z1 - z2)) > tolerance:
            return False

    return True
```

This updated code checks for division by zero and uses a tolerance to handle cases where points belong to the same plane. It should be more robust and work for a wider range of cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the next approach:
-make a line through two first points in parametric form
-find length of perpendicular projections for other points onto this line using scalar(dot) product
-compare projection length with tolerance

```
def are_colinear(points, tolerance):
    dx01 = points[1][0]-points[0][0]
    dy01 = points[1][1]-points[0][1]
    dz01 = points[1][2]-points[0][2]
    mult = 1.0 / (dx01*dx01+dy01*dy01+dz01*dz01)
    for i in range(2, len(points)):
        cdx = points[i][0] - points[0][0]
        cdy = points[i][1] - points[0][1]
        cdz = points[i][2] - points[0][2]
        t = (cdx*dx01+cdy*dy01+cdz*dz01) * mult
        perplen = math.sqrt((t*dx01-cdx)**2+ (t*dy01-cdy)**2 +(t*dz01-cdz)**2)
        if perplen > tolerance:
            return False
    return True

 print(are_colinear([[0,0,0],[2,2,2],[1,0.9999999,1.0000001]], 1e-6))
 print(are_colinear([[0,0,0],[2,2,2],[1,0.9999,1.00001]], 1e-6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses! I thought a little and came up with an implementation that uses the cross product of vectors. We select one point as the origin (Thanks to Dillon Davis for this idea) and calculate relative coordinates of remaining points, which at the same time are coordinates of vectors coming from the origin. If all these vectors lie on the same line, the cross product of any pair of vectors must be equal to zero vector. Composing a loop to check this condition, we get the following function:

```
def are_colinear(points, tolerance):
if len(points) < 3:
    return True

x0, y0, z0 = points.pop(0) # the origin
translated_points = [(x - x0, y - y0, z - z0) for x, y, z in points]

for i in range(len(translated_points) - 1):
    x1, y1, z1 = translated_points[i]
    x2, y2, z2 = translated_points[i + 1]

    xy = (y1*z2 - z1*y2, z1*x2 - x1*z2, x1*y2 - y1*x2) # the cross product

    len_xy = (xy[0]**2 + xy[1]**2 + xy[2]**2)**0.5

    if 0 <= abs(len_xy) <= tolerance:
        continue
    else:
        return False
return True
```